# Python module pseudo compiler idea.

Tags: python

Say I work for a python project, in folder myfolder/

it has a library file "Mylibrary.py" and a script file "myscript.py"

and in myscript.py I imported Mylibrary.py, is there a program such that it will replace "import Mylibrary" by my library file literally and replace all function call "Mylibrary.myfunction" by "myfunction"? It kind of like "compile" multiple python scripts into one. Or this would be a terrible solution

The reason is that I want to use myscript as an executable in other folders without having to copy multiple files or making a package.

Comment: Are you looking for `from Mylibrary import *`? This imports all the functions from `Mylibrary` into the global scope.

Comment: @Haidro No this is looking for the equivalent of #include

Comment: @jozefg Ah alright. I'm not familiar with that

Comment: Will packaging all you need into a zip file and [running it](http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2012/05/21/python-zip-files/) help you?

Comment: @Bogdan, cool, didn't know this. still would be nice to have a program to sort out the dependence for you. So run "magic myscript.py" it will create that zip file for you. (I am lazy, I know..)

Comment: There are things like [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) or [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) that walk through dependencies to create a standalone executable. Take a look at them, perhaps they can do it "half-way" and just collect all the dependencies in a folder.